# controlling the resolution (dpi) of an exported JPG from highcharts exporting-server

Tags: highcharts

I have read the recent posts on the Highcharts.com website regarding their updated PhantomJS based exporting-server. I have also cloned their github repository and successfully compiled their web-service. However, all files produced by this server are marked as 96dpi, which is inadequate for my purposes. According to somewhat contradictory information on the Highcharts.com website ([Here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) and [Here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs)), they are using Batik to rasterize PNG and JPG output, which should make it possible to adjust the DPI settings of the exported raster images. However, the pom.xml doesn't include any batik references and I can't find anything in the source code which indicates that anything other than PhantomJS is being used to produce the raster renditions.  The PhantomJS export might be able to adjust the DPI, but I can only find the scale and width options which don't directly adjust the DPI, thus requiring a tedious post-processing rescale (or metadata edit) to adjust the DPI accordingly.

So, the meat of my question: how to adjust the exported DPI of a highcharts chart in PNG and JPG format when using the highcharts java exporting-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release before the last one used both Batik and PhantomJS. The last release uses only PhantomJS. This is why you do not find any Batik references in the pom.xml anymore.

For controlling the dpi of the exported image. You should use the scale parameter. For completeness sake, here is how Highcharts determines the dpi of the exported image.

**Controling the size of the exported image**

Since Highcharts 3.0 and Highstock 1.3, the size of the exported image is computed based on a few rules:

1. If the exporting.sourceWidth and exporting.sourceHeight options are set, they take predence. This provides a convenient way of having separate sizes of the on-screen chart and the exported one.
2. If not, and the chart.width and chart.height options are set, those are used for the exported chart.
3. If a size hasn't been found yet, and the containing div has an explicit pixel width or height, that width or height is used. Percentage and other non-pixel widths will not take effect. This prevents a common pitfall in Highcharts 2, where charts with the typical 100% width would look out of proportion in export.
4. If a size still hasn't been found, it defaults to 600 by 400 pixels.
5. After rendering the chart width the above size, and all text sizes in relation to that, the actual image resolution is determined by exporting.scale which defaults to 2. In practice this means that a 600x400 chart will return an image of 1200x800 pixels by default. The rationale behind this is quite simple - if we used a scale of 1 and just set the sourceWidth to 1200 and sourceHeight to 800, all the text would become too small. And if we didn't scale it up, the resolution would be too small for print.

Read also [here](http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-module) for more on the export server

Comment: I've learned in the last day that the problem is PhantomJS itself. PhantomJS uses 96dpi on Windows and 72dpi on Linux. The problem is indirectly addressed by the following PhantomJS defect: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10659 It doesn't matter how large the pixel width of the output raster is, in my situation, I'm using a publishing system which uses the DPI setting in the PNG or JPG to determine the physical width. So a 72dpi image of 720 pixels wide is exactly 10" wide in the output. "

Comment: To be clear, the scale and chart.width affect the physical size of the graphic. Adjustable DPI would allow a higher-quality image to be smaller on the physical page.  Yes, using "scale" parameter allows a higher resolution image to be built, but it would require post-processing the resulting PNG to change the internal DPI setting from 72/96 in order to take advantage of that larger size. (BTW the current highcharts-convert.js ignores exporting.scale in favor of the scale HTTP argument, which is also inconvenient for me, I'm hoping to fix that and send you a pull request.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the dpi issue. I opened a [issue#1903](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1903) on Github to solve the inconsistency of ignoring the exporting.scale option. And the answer to your question on changing the dpi, is that it's not  possible. PhantomJS uses a standard dpi of 72 which can't be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suggest that moving back to using Batik might be in order since PhantomJS doesn't support adjustable DPI rendering. (On windows, PhantomJS uses a variable DPI and can be anything from 96 to 120).  Hopefully PhantomJS v2.0 with QT5 will support adjustable DPI.